Avoiding Duplicate Prospects with Bi-Directional Sync Between Salesforce and Pardot
Hello Salesforce Community,
I’m working with a client on their lead management process using Pardot and Salesforce Sales Cloud. According to their needs we plan to implemented the following setup:

Every form submission in Pardot creates a new Lead in Salesforce,
regardless of whether the email address already exists as a Lead or
Contact
Our client wants to enable bi-directional sync so that any
Lead or Contact created in Salesforce automatically creates a
corresponding Prospect in Pardot.

Here’s my concern:
If an existing customer (a Contact in Salesforce) submits a new form, this will create a new Lead in Salesforce. My question is, will this new Lead trigger the creation of a duplicate Prospect in Pardot, even though the email address already exists?
I understand that Pardot typically matches based on email address, but I’m unsure how this would play out with a bi-directional sync and the process of creating new Leads in Salesforce. Does anyone have experience with this setup or advice on how to prevent duplicate Prospects in Pardot while still meeting the client’s requirements?
Thanks in advance for any guidance!

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_admin_ampsea_parent.htm&type=5
